# Dice game (simulating many throws with 3 dices)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I am trying to code a dice game:

How do I write a function that is supposed to simulate 1000 throws of 3 dice and print the number of times a throw resulted in exactly 2 of the dice, but not all 3, landing on the same number. Meaning not (1,2,3) or (5,5,5), but like this (1,2,2).

```
def throw():
```

I know I need to use the random- library to generate numbers between 1 and 6.

What I need is example code on how I can approach this and what to do.

Comment: This isn't a good match for stack overflow as you don't have a specific problem; you're best going to a python forum or chatroom to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

The function could be something like this:

```
import random
matches = 0
for i in range(1000):  # 1000 throws
    result = (random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)) # three dices randomly from 1 to 6 in a tuple (list)
    for i in range(1,7): # count from 1 to 6
        if result.count(i) == 2:
            matches += 1
            break # breaking out of this for-loop for performance improvement
print("Got "+str(matches)+" matches.")
```

Of course, this code could be heavily improved. But according to your question I assume that you are quite new to Python programming. This is why I tried to write a code that is self-explanatory.

Meta: please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for specific coding. It's intended to be a place where you **provide** code which contains error that you are unable to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and list comprehension to generate the throw:

```
for i in range(1000):
    throw = [random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(3)]
```

Then just write code to check your condition, something like:

```
valid = any([throw.count(i) == 2 for i in range(1, 6)])
```

Then if it's valid is `True` you can do with it what you need.